# Can't disable one SIM card in my dual SIM phone running CyanogenMod 12.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, dual-sim, samsung-galaxy-s-duos-2

I have a dual SIM Galaxy S Duos 2. I'm unable to disable individual SIMs. There's no option in Settings. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You don't have a SIM option like in this picture?:http://www.asus.com/zentalk/data/attachment/forum/201507/13/082546qba47ujdfupx4bu4.png.thumb.jpg You could try this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pt.joaormf.mtkcontrol&hl=en

Comment: @AndroidDev This app is for Mediatek devices I guess.. N my device is not compatible with it,I saw the list. Mine is broadcom